Conditionally matriculated in PhD program
I am an engineering MASc student and received a conditional acceptance to a PhD program in Mechanical Engineering for Fall 2024. One of the admission conditions was the successful completion of my MASc by early August. However, my MASc oral exam is scheduled for late August, which is after this deadline.
I have previously reached out to the graduate admission committee about this issue and got this response: you will be condition matriculated in the program in late August. What exactly does this mean and entail? Will I be considered as an MASc student this Fall semester, and once I graduate be officially enroled into the PhD program? Or will I be considered provisionally as a PhD student, and be granted full admission upon completion of my MASc requirements?
My supervisor will likely be the same as my MASc, so will they also begin as my PhD supervisor in Fall, or only after I am officially enrolled, since a supervisor has not been officially assigned yet, only I have stated my current Master's supervisor as my preferred PhD supervisor?

Only that program can tell you what they will do.

They told you that you will be matriculated into the Ph.D. once you have passed your MASc orals. If this answer is for some reason not sufficient, you need to ask them (and not the internet) for clarification.

The underlying meaning, hidden in bureaucratic language is that you have been accepted conditional on passing the masters exams. Should you fail them, you will be dropped.
Effectively, it likely means that you can proceed just as if you have been fully matriculated, but you'd better pass. The language is just to cover themselves should you fail.
You can, and should, ask them yourself, but any other interpretation would seem outside the bounds of decency. They aren't, I certainly hope, playing a game with you.
Edited to add: If, for some reason, your exam gets delayed, then you will need to renegotiate with them what they are willing to do. Don't let that happen.
